# Method not Firing properly when called from other form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

My project has 2 forms (A & B), when form A loads the focus is set to a Devexpress Repository Text Edit Item.

During the Form B `FormClosing` method form A `btnRefresh.PerformClick` method is called.

This fills table adapters etc. It should also move the focus back to the Repository Text Edit Item. If I physically click the Refresh Button it works as expected.

Regardless of how I call the method, it doesnt move the focus.

**Method 1**

```
frmFormA.MoveFocus()
```

**Method 2**

```
Public Class FormB
dim form as FormA = nothing

Public Sub New(ByVal calling As Form)
form = DirectCast(calling, FormA)
End Sub

Private Sub FormB_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
form.btnRefresh.performClick()
End Sub
```

I am not getting any errors and I can see from `Debug.Print` that the methods are being called either way.

Any further ideas on what I can try?

Comment: Doesn't look like FormB_FormClosing is handling a closing event.

Comment: Sorry, I typed it out and didn't copy it. Edited the code.

Comment: FormB is still "alive" when you are calling the performClick, so you can't change the focus yet.  Is FormB being shown with ShowDialog?  If so, change the focus after that line.

Comment: PerformClick() does *not* move the focus.  Clicking the button with the mouse does.  And the button's Focus() method does.  Most basic problem is that you don't have a reference to the button object.  You'll make your life a *lot* easier by putting the FormClosed event handler in FormA.  Where it belongs.

Comment: LarsTech & Hans Passant, that solved the problem! Thank you.